# How to redirect only subdomain to Firebase

Tags: firebase, dns

Completely new to Firebase. Just developed a web app with Realtime DB and hosting at `xxx.web.app`. It works.

Now I want to host this at `xxx.mydomain.com`. However, DNS must be updated only for this subdomain. I have the main domain and other subdomains hosted elsewhere. Is this possible? Could you point to relevant docs how to achieve this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You would just need to setup the DNS for that ``xxx` subdomain to point to your Firebase hosting:
[image]

In this example I have bith `www` and `api` pointing to Firebase because I host both there. You culd just change your ``xxx` to point to Firebase.

Comment: On your domain provider like GoDaddy in my case.